# Access JavaScript object at position/key 0

Tags: javascript

I am trying to access parts of a JavaScript object where the highest level key is 'randomly generated'. Basically instead of referring to the object as:

```
json.keyName[0].somethingElse.somethingElseElse[0]
```

I want to access it by:

```
json[0][0].somethingElse.somethingElseElse[0]
```

because I can't predict the keyName value.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get hold of a key without knowing its name using [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys).

```
Object.keys({ a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 });
// returns [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ]
```

We can use this to get the first key out of an object and look up the corresponding value.

```
var firstKey = Object.keys(obj)[0];
console.log(obj[firstKey]);
```

However, the order in which the keys end up in the array is not guaranteed to be the same as in the initial object. As an object is much closer to a traditional map than a sorted map.

Comment: A side note: since ES2015 the order will be guaranteed as per creation order.

Comment: That's good to know. Can't find much on it in the spec though, is it inferred from the internal `[[OwnPropertyKeys]]` method? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks so much, this answers and helps me perfectly!

Comment: @DanPrince I haven't checked the spec that deep, I just remember that Axel Rauschmayer mentioned it somewhere in his book and articles.